# Methods for geohash of polygon?

Tags: polygon, latitude-longitude, compression, geohash

GeoHash is an excellent method to code the latitude and longitude of a point into a string. It's concise, due to the use of numbers + letters, and the precision can be tuned adding characters at the end.

I'm looking for an equivalent method to code polygons, not points. I saw two ways to do it:

- geohash all polygon points, then concatenate them, and then compress the resulting string using classical text compression algorithms.
- reference all geohashes included into the polygon. It's the RecursivePrefixTree method - see http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2014/04/11/indexing-polygons-in-lucene-with-accuracy/.

I would like the code could be manipulated by humans, ie. manually copied, not only by machines as an index.

Edit: see also the discussion (in French) at http://seenthis.net/messages/269838.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, are you open to use any python/geo library?

Comment: Clearly yes. But the question is more about concepts and algorithms than implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Georaptor](https://github.com/ashwin711/georaptor). Creates a compressed set of geohashes, i.e., a combination of geohashes at different levels.

Comment: Note that ElasticSearch is using the same strategy for polygons indexing: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html

Answer (score 3):

The most robust implementation is in the [s2 geometry library](http://code.google.com/p/s2-geometry-library/) with its Polygon Cover implementation. Uses S2CellIds, an improvement upon GeoHashes, as its unit.

Answer (score 1):

With recent release by Google of [Open Location Code](http://openlocationcode.com), there was a good questioning about Geohash. Infortunately, I didn't see something about polygons Geohash.

As you are looking for various implementations for Geohash like solutions, look at Google comparison of various algorithms and solutions at https://github.com/google/open-location-code/blob/master/docs/comparison.adoc

It's clearly for points but it may help you for your polygon Geohash "quest".

Answer (score 1):

A very simple implementation would be to perform BFS filling the polygon with the geohashes. Then you can recursively breakdown the edges into higher precision.

[image]

Here's an example 
[Example BFS](http://68.183.29.243/BFSGeoHashNoOptimization/driver.html)

Answer (score 0):

The PostGIS function [ST_GeoHash](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeoHash.html) returns a GeoHash based on the input geometry type. Of course, any geometry other than a Point would result in lower precision.